# Java exiting entire program when parsing an input file

Tags: java, file, oop, netbeans, file-io

I am getting an error in my code which I cannot seem to wrap my head around. In my code I am parsing a data file and setting the values to my local variables that will later be turned into an object and added to the productList. But Somewhere in my while loop, the program stops running and 
1 is printed to standard out and it says build successful (im using netbeans)
I tried catching the exception and printing it out using e.getmessage() but nothing will print and I know for a fact the error is in the try block because I used print statements to find out when the error occurs. This method is also inside a menu function that is not supposed to end the method input finishes.

```
public void input(ArrayList productList) {
    String type = "";
    String name = "";
    String authors = "";
    String publisher = "";
    String maker = "";
    String productID = "";
    String priceS = "";
    String yearS = "";

    String filepath = "/home/alex/Desktop/CS/products.txt";
    try{
        File f = new File(filepath);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String theData = sc.nextLine();
            if(theData.contains("type")){
                type = theData;
            } else if(theData.contains("productID")){
                productID = theData;
            } else if(theData.contains("name")){
                name = theData;
            } else if(theData.contains("price")){
                priceS = theData;
            } else if(theData.contains("year")){
                yearS = theData;
            } else if(theData.contains("maker")){
                maker = theData;
            } else if(theData.contains("authors")){
                authors = theData;
            } else if(theData.contains("publisher")){
                publisher = theData;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use your IDE's debugger to see exactly what's happening?

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` is a better way to expose exception information.

Comment: I got no errors running your code. When you say _I tried catching the exception and printing it out using e.getmessage() but nothing will print and I know for a fact the error is in the try block because I used print statements to find out when the error occurs._ Then WHERE did the error occur? If the catch Exception did not print the `“Error: “ e.getMessage()`, Then an exception NEVER occurred. How do you, _know for a fact the error is in the try block because I used print statements to find out when the error occurs_ Where is this print statement to indicate where the error is?